# Find a sequence in time series with Matlab

Tags: matlab, sequence

I want to write a short Matlab function for finding the sequence values in a time series like this:

Ex: a = [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0];

My_expected_result = 3 ;(as number 1 happens 3 time of sequences)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)-based solution to find the number of runs of ones:

```
result = numel(regexp(char(a+'0'), '1+'));
```

You can also use [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html), which works for numerical arrays (although that's not documented):

```
result = numel(strfind([0 a], [1 0]));
```

Or just [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html):

```
result = sum(diff([a 0])<0);
```

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) can be used for the job too:

```
result = max(bwlabel(a));
```

or (thanks to [@rahnema1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6579744/rahnema1) for this one):

```
[~, result] = bwlabel(a);
```

Comment: Great! This is what i want. But i don't understand number (48) what does it mean?

Comment: That's ASCII code for `'0'`. I have edited for clarity. It is used for transforming numbers into corresponding chars

Comment: Thank you so much. I sit whole day to look for this, and you helped me. Thanks

Comment: @HongQuan Glad I could help!

Comment: Bah, beat me to bwlabel :(

Comment: This is very complete. Can’t think of any other sensical method. :(

Comment: I tried with `strsplit` but I could only get the clunky `nnz(cellfun(@numel, strsplit(char([a+'0']), '0')))`